# Spring Integration Fetch SQL Data after the Flow starts

Tags: spring-integration

Have an integration flow which polls a JMS queue and for each message, using a field from the message data need to fire a SELECT query and then split the results from it for further processing.

How do I run a SELECT query in the mid of the flow using Java DSL? Tried with `JdbcOutboundGateway` and it is expecting the `Poller` object.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `JdbcOutboundGateway` is the correct way to solve your task. It does not require the poller. That's endpoint which is going to call this `JdbcOutboundGateway` expects the poller. Just because the input channel is a `QueueChannel` in your case. Not sure why would one need a queue just after a JMS queue...

Spring Integration model is like this:

```
channel -> endpoint (poller) -> message handler (-> channel)
```

Whatever is in the parentheses ч is optional and depend on the channel and message handler implementation, respectively.

Comment: `JdbcOutboundGateway` worked, earlier error was due to mismatch with selectQuery and updateQuery. Understood it better after reading https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/jdbc.html#jdbc-outbound-gateway. Thx for your help